# MailChimp + tumblr

Tags: popup, mailchimp

I was wondering if someone can help me.

I've been looking online for a couple of hours but I can't find a solution yet.

Basically the coding of my tumblr must be the one that causes perhaps issues with the popup I did set up with MailChimp.

As you can see on the image the title of the website show up, and I also realise that it's impossible to close the window of the popup on my phone.

I's annoying because everything works fine via a computer, but the mobile version is just bad.

Screenshot:

[image: image here]

Link: https://aab-ad-soaps.tumblr.com/

Comment: Hi there, anyone knows perhaps how to fix this? :)

Comment: This is a knowledge database, not a chat box. Please edit your post as a comprehensible self contained question, not as a chat message. It would significantly raise your chance to get an answer.